# ¿Cómo hacer un ranking de una determinada puntuacion?

Tags: java, android

Hice un juego donde te daban una determinada puntuación, por ejemplo 56. Esa puntuación , esa variable, la he conseguido llevar a la siguiente activity( a mi ranking que quiero completar) para que se muestre en un editText o textview, me es indiferente, pero lo he conseguido, pero tengo varios problemas.

El primero de ellos y el gran problema es que cuando hago por ejemplo esos 56 puntos y me sale en la siguiente pantalla la puntuación( en el ranking deseado), al salirme de la aplicación no se me guarda y al volver a jugar está a 0 y en la primera línea vuelve a salirme la puntuación nueva que acabo de jugar y así indenifinidamente...

Lo que necesito es que al hacer una puntuación se sitúe en primer lugar y que al salir de la app y volver a entrar, al entrar en "rankings" esté ahí siempre y que si hago otra se sitúe en el textview que tengo en segundo lugar.

Para eso, he creado un AdminSQLiteOpenHelper que es para las bases de datos pues hice una app paralela para probar y guardar datos al dar en el botón "alta" y al pinchar en "consultar" me salían unos datos que yo había guardado en "alta" y los he combinado en esta app. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que la puntuación se guarde  automáticamente , sin clickar en ningún siti y que siempre que entre esté ahí...

Mi código de "alta" y "consulta" que muestro a continuación es donde necesito poner que cuando acabe el juego esa puntuación se guarde solo y se muestre solo automaticamente, de ahí que cree funciones "alta" y "consulta":

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pararanking);
    Intent intent2= getIntent(); 
    value3 = intent2.getIntExtra("parametro",0); 

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et1.setText("1 "+value3);
}
```

public void alta(View v) {

```
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion", null, 1); //Creamos instancia llamada Admin
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Creamos base de datos y writable para decir que es totalmende modificable

    String dni = et1.getText().toString();

    ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();  //Clase para guardar datos

    //LO QUE HAY ENTRE COMILLAS ES LO MISMO LLAMADA EN LA CLASE SQLITE DE JAVA,IMPORTANTE LOS NOMBRES.
    registro.put("dni", dni);


    bd.insert("votantes", null, registro); //null siempre por defecto
    bd.close(); //Cerramos si no da problemas.

    et1.setText("");


    Toast.makeText(this, "Se cargaron los datos de la puntuacion",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //CARTEL TOAST PARA AVISAR A USER. 
}
public void consulta(View v) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
            "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.

 //   String dni = et2.getText().toString();//Me interesa solo dni porque es lo que voy a consultar

    Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery(  //devuelve 0 o 1 fila //es una consulta
           "select nombre,colegio,nromesa  from votantes where dni=" +value3, null);
//    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {  //si ha devuelto 1 fila, vamos al primero (que es el unico)

//    } else
    et2.setText(fila.getString(0));
        Toast.makeText(this, "No existe una persona con dicho dni" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bd.close(); //Cerramos la base
}
```

-------------- LAYOUT DEL RANKING--------

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="alta"
    android:text="alta" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="consulta"
      android:onClick="consulta" />
```

----------- CÓDIGO DE SQLITE --------------

public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
//ESTO ES EL CONSTRUCTOR, NECESARIO PARA EL SQLITE CON ESOS PARÁMETROS, TE LO DICE ÉL SOLO.
public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     db.execSQL("create table votantes(dni integer primary key, nombre text, colegio text, nromesa integer)");
     //Creamos tabla (Tiene que estar escrito así sí o sí.
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //Cuando hacemos un upgrade borramos tabla(con drop) y se crea con nuevos valores, por eso esto(create table).
     db.execSQL("drop table if exists votantes");
     db.execSQL("create table votantes(dni integer primary key, nombre text, colegio text, nromesa integer)");

}
```

}

Llevo ya muchas preguntas sobre esto y muchisimas horas tiradas a la basura y he decidido poner el máximo código posible para obtener ayuda pues lo que busco en resumen es que al hacer una puntuación salga en la activity "rankings" (Esta parte está conseguida) pero que esa puntuación se quede guardada automáticamente y salga SIEMPRE, para eso os he puesto la función "alta" y "consulta" para ver cómo se haría pues a mí con lo que tiene no me sale.

Comment: ¿Esta puntuación que deseas guardar solo debe ser del usuario en su dispositivo o debe estar disponible para el usuario en la misma aplicación a través de diversos dispositivos o debe mostrar la puntuación a nivel regional/mundial? En base a ello se aplicaría una solución

Comment: Mi idea principal es hacerlo on-line, a modo de play games, por google, pero como ya pregunté y busqué en información y no me aclaré , para evitar la misma respuesta, me gustaría que fuera cada uno en su propio dispositivo... aunque lo ideal (y lo que en un principio busco) es a nivel de que cuando yo entro en el dispositivo de quien sea se quede guardada mi información.

Comment: Así que ayudadme para que sea a nivel regional/mundial, he dado el código y daria más si hace falta pero creo que lo esencial está, entonces, cómo hago para que se me almacene a nivel global en cada dispositivo, con lo que tengo?

Comment: El tema es bien simple: debes almacenar el puntaje de los jugadores en alguna fuente de datos que esté disponible a nivel mundial mediante servicios y consultar allí por notificaciones. Tu código no apunta a eso, por ende no lo lograrás con un almacenamiento local. Te recomiendo ver algo como firebase o tener tu propio repositorio de datos en la nube quizás con Amazon.

Comment: Luiggi, como hacerlo encontes para que mi código apunte a eso? Pues me gustaría hacer más de este tipo y quiero que se almacene a nivel global. Eso de amazon le echaré un vistazo... porque si no tengo ya marcha atrás con esta app...

Comment: El algoritmo es simple: almacenas como llave-valor el usuario y su puntuación en una fuente de datos. Luego, ante otra partida finalizada, buscas si el puntaje obtenido para este jugador es mayor al que ya existe, de ser así lo actualizas. Para obtener el listado de los 5 usuarios con mayor puntuación, obtienes los N puntajes más altos de tu fuente de datos y muestras consigo a los usuarios. No es difícil de implementar. Ahora, que la fuente de datos esté en la nube o cosas similares solo cambia un poco la implementación, pero la idea central se mantiene.

Comment: El problema es esa fuente de datos... que no tengo experiencia con eso y no sé como implementarlo, las ideas posteriores y tal si, pero eso no...

Comment: Pues entonces ya sabes sobre qué investigar. No conozco mucho del tema, pero sí sé sobre el "divide y vencerás": divide el problema grande o complejo en pequeños problemas que se pueden resolver uno a uno, resuelve cada uno de esos problemas y tendrás el problema complejo resuelto, si cada problema pequeño sigue siendo complejo, aplicar "divide y vencerás" recursivamente. Así que, al parecer, lo que falta es que revises el tema de cómo utilizar esa fuente de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es la combinación de diferentes tecnologías. A ver...

> El primero de ellos y el gran problema es que cuando hago por ejemplo esos 56 puntos y me sale en la siguiente pantalla la puntuación( en el ranking deseado), al salirme de la aplicación no se me guarda y al volver a jugar está a 0 y en la primera línea vuelve a salirme la puntuación nueva que acabo de jugar y así indenifinidamente...

Para resolver esto puedes usar una base de datos local con SQLite por ejemplo o un simple [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

> Para eso, he creado un AdminSQLiteOpenHelper que es para las bases de datos pues hice una app paralela para probar y guardar datos al dar en el botón "alta" y al pinchar en "consultar" me salían unos datos que yo había guardado en "alta" y los he combinado en esta app. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que la puntuación se guarde automáticamente , sin clickar en ningún siti y que siempre que entre esté ahí...

Para guardarlo automáticamente puedes tener como referencia algún evento, en vez de un botón, pues por ejemplo cuando se sale de la ventana X o simplemente cuando se muestran las puntuaciones.

Si quisieras hacer el ranking global accesible para todos los usuarios tendrías que crear una base de datos en un servidor dónde almacenar los usuarios y asociarles las puntuaciones de las partidas, una vez hecho esto el obtener el ranking es lo más sencillo del mundo y puede hacerse con una simple consulta a la base de datos.

Si no tienes experiencia creando la parte del servidor puedes utilizar servicios como Firebase pero personalmente te recomendaría que tratases de hacerlo tú a mano sin utilizar estos servicios ya que aprenderás muchísimo más y te servirá para un futuro